# Meaningful upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^T \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^T\Big)^{-1} v_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $n \ge d$. Assume that the matrix $A$ is invertible.
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^T 
$$

Is it possible to simplify the expression
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^T A^{-1} v_i?$$

Or obtain a simple upper bound in terms of $v_i$'s.

For the case when $d=1$ it is straightforward to see that the expression simplifies and is always equal to $1$. I wonder what tricks there are in understanding the behavior of this function.

Comment: You shouldn’t use $i$ for both sum.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes autocorrect seems to delete contractions.  @Hyperplane

Comment: Use $x^\mathsf{T} y = \mathrm{trace}(yx^\mathsf{T})$ to get $ = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{trace}(A^{-1} v_i v_i^\mathsf{T}) = \mathrm{trace}(A^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n v_iv_i^\mathsf{T}) = \mathrm{trace}(A^{-1} A) = \mathrm{trace}(I_d) = d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^T A^{-1} v_j
= \sum_{j=1}^n  ⟨ A^{-1}∣ v_jv_j^T⟩
= ⟨ A^{-1}∣ \sum_{j=1}^n v_jv_j^T⟩
= ⟨ A^{-1}∣ A ⟩
$$

And we can apply Cauchy-Schwartz

$$|⟨ A^{-1}∣ A ⟩| ≤ ‖A^{-1}‖⋅‖A‖ = κ(A)$$

However, since $A$ is symmetric by definition, we even have

$$⟨ A^{-1}∣ A ⟩ = ⟨ A^⊤ A^{-1}∣ _d⟩  = ⟨ A A^{-1}∣ _d⟩ = ⟨ _d ∣ _d⟩ = d$$

Comment: oh, thanks. So this expression is always of constant $d$. Thanks again